# Rails 4, stylesheet present but will not load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

In my new app using Rails4 and ruby2.2  I set up the scaffold and the database. Put content into product.css.scss and make a simple index page. When I start the server the stylesheet shows up in firebug  but does  not load into the page. This is the terminal output when the page loads. Note that products.....css is GOT.

```
 Started GET "/products/" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:49 +0000
    Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
      Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
      Rendered products/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 67ms (Views: 66.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)


    Started GET "/assets/products-4e4513638d9521b9efce9b4a8b4e831a.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:50 +0000


    Started GET "/assets/scaffolds-8303c55245261085d0bbcdc67eb2a91f.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:50 +0000


    Started GET "/assets/jquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:50 +0000


    Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs-e27bd20a10d28155845a22d71ef94f2f.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:50 +0000


    Started GET "/assets/turbolinks-da8ddad9c2c5483d4c5c30c1ce325253.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:50 +0000


    Started GET "/assets/products-46c9a194bd0668e67d57241f94473dc8.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-02-19 19:33:50 +0000` <title> Depot </title>
```

This is from the generated source

```
<title> Depot </title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-0197bf3693ae0b690bfba9f2f2d33f8d.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/products-4e4513638d9521b9efce9b4a8b4e831a.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/scaffolds-8303c55245261085d0bbcdc67eb2a91f.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true">

<script src="/assets/jquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs-e27bd20a10d28155845a22d71ef94f2f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks-da8ddad9c2c5483d4c5c30c1ce325253.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/products-46c9a194bd0668e67d57241f94473dc8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application-7940349aecc5b83c3832ad0db52d27df.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="r/8eGQf0UO72Jq2ogcLAqkgEFyJH6MjHU/+ayZbr4/k+Zwv0WwNkdZ7aep+p9bmGS6wJSYcdOC33luzQrE5J3g==">

 </head>
```

Does anybody know why the stylesheet won't load?

products-4e4513638d9521b9efce9b4a8b4e831a.css doesn't exist/get created in public assets??? However images and javascript do.

Comment: look at application.css in assets/stylesheets/ and see whether there are `*= require_tree .` and `*= require_self` ?

Comment: They are there and judging by the code above *= require_tree . is working

Comment: Your error is unclear. You are getting `404` when loading the asset? The css doesn't contain the content you expected? It seems like it is in the source and the server is getting it so your problem isn't clear. What do you mean, "won't load"?

Comment: The page loads but with no styling.

Comment: I'm not posting this as answer  because I don't know how or why it worked. I copied the contents of products.scss.css to scaffolds.scss.css and when loaded the html I got a styled page. Then I put the original code back into scaffolds.scss.css and still got a  page styled by products.scss.css. And both the files are  in app/assets/stylesheets not public/assets/stylesheets.  I'll keep doing it this way  as long as it works.